# How to do a memset with Python buffer object?

Tags: python, wxpython, buffer, python-2.5

How can I do a fast reset for a continue set of values inside a Python buffer object?

Mainly I am looking for a memset :)

PS. The solution should work with Python 2.5 and modify the buffer itself (no copy).

Comment: how do you create your buffer object ?

Comment: It is returned by WxImage.GetDataBuffer(), you can write to it using `buf[0]=chr(0)` but I want to write an entire set of values with speed instead of using for loops.

Comment: Just a comment.. memset could be useful when handling cryptographically sensitive data. Example: destroying the plaintext password after encrypting it. `del`ling the name or binding it to another object is inadequate; the plaintext object could still persist in memory for a while before being garbage-collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ctypes package has a memset function built right in. Ctypes does work with Python 2.5, but is not included by default. You will need a separate install.

```
def memsetObject(bufferObject):
    "Note, dangerous"
    import ctypes
    data = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)()
    size = ctypes.c_int()  # Note, int only valid for python 2.5
    ctypes.pythonapi.PyObject_AsCharBuffer(ctypes.py_object(bufferObject), ctypes.pointer(data), ctypes.pointer(size))
    ctypes.memset(data, 0, size.value)

testObject = "sneakyctypes"
memsetObject(testObject)
print repr(testObject)
# '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can write into, try with [itertools.repeat()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

```
import itertools
my_buffer[:] = itertools.repeat(0, len(my_buffer))
```

Comment: What does that `:` means inside the square brace ?

Comment: @shuva those `:` indicates that we are taking existing buffer as an iterator (all the elements of the buffer) and replace them with the newly created elements. It will replace the content of `my_buffer`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the values to zero, you can use this:

```
size = ...
buffer = bytearray(size)
```

or possibly:

```
buffer[:] = bytearray(size)
```